# Can't load the *.ttf font file as binary string in jspdf

Tags: javascript, html, jspdf

I want to add a custom font in `jsPDF` but I can't load the `*.ttf` font file as binary string.

Please give me solution of it or any others way to add custom font in `jsPDF`.

```
var doc = new jsPDF();

var myFont =  // load the *.ttf font file as binary string

// add the font to jsPDF
doc.addFileToVFS("CustomFont.ttf", myFont);
doc.addFont("CustomFont.ttf", "CustomFont", "normal");
doc.text("অশোক, টাটা, দাইয়ু, ফাও, ভলভো কিছুই", 10, 10);
doc.save("BanglaText.pdf");
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have to set the font as well ?

```
doc.addFont("CustomFont.ttf", "CustomFont", "normal");
doc.setFont('CustomFont');
doc.text("অশোক, টাটা, দাইয়ু, ফাও, ভলভো কিছুই", 10, 10);
```